# Which one is more British: "car hire" or "rent a car"?

Tags: word-choice, british-english

I am wondering which one is more commonly used in the United Kingdom: *car hire* or *rent a car*?

Comment: Well, "rent a car" is definitely the more common phrase in the U.S., so if "car hire" is a popular phrase in any English-speaking country, it's somewhere other than the U.S.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In British usage (at least up to the last few decades)

- "rent" is used for (real) property only: houses, flats, offices,
  factories
- "hire" is used for any kind of moveable property: cars, costumes, marquees, glasses (for a party), scaffolding, chainsaws ...

("hire" is not used for people: rather "employ" or "engage").

I qualified this because American usage is now recognised here, and I would guess is used by some people.

But "car hire" and "hire car" are both common expressions still.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please expain: we ***never*** use "hire" for people (therefore, "hire a guide" isn't correct)?

Comment: Hmm. Never say 'never'. ;-) Until American expressions were imported, _hire_ was never used in the UK in the sense of "give somebody a job". I don't think we'd even have used it for casual employees (it's hard to remember for sure). But "hire a guide" sounds OK to me - I think it is conceiving a guide as a service, like a taxi. FWIW, looking up "[Hire] a person" in GloWbE gives instances of  0.13/mil in Canada, 0.09/mil in US, but 0.03/mil in UK and Irelnd

Comment: Thank you! I met this expression in a Russian English school book and decided to ask :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that *car hire* is more common in the UK.

Comment: I would suggest it too, but unless you present some evidence or argument, who is to know if you are right or not.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the posts by Loquacity and JoseK:

*Rentacar* was trademarked in the US at some point, but this company seems to have faltered in the meantime.

The trademark for *Rentacar* Etymonline is referring to was originally filed on 15 November 1923 by *The Rentacar Company* in Toledo, OH. They claimed use since 6 August 1921. The original entry in the *Official Gazette of the United States Post Office* of 19 February 1924 can be found [here](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Official_Gazette_of_the_United_States_Pa/rel1RELkHa4C?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=Rentacar&pg=RA1-PA514-IA35&printsec=frontcover).

I couldn't find much else about the company. There was, however, a court case in 1928 before the Ohio Court of Appeals, where a man had rented a car from The Rentacar Company without having a driver's license and had killed someone in an accident. The question was whether someone with a license who was driving with him could be held as liable as if they were the car's owner. (The answer was yes: [case opinion](https://casetext.com/case/aurend-v-schroeder-admr).)

There was also a 1931 court case by the Circuit Court of Appeals, Sixth Circuit, involving the same people brought forth by the insurance company hired by the Rentacar Company, whether there was a breach of contract that made the insurance policy invalid. (There wasn't and it didn't: [judgment](https://www.leagle.com/decision/193177548f2d7271523).)

It's been 11 years since your question, but this was just too interesting not to post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the UK, but I would suggest that "hire car" is a more equivalent term for "rent-a-car" than "car hire". I tend to think of "car hire" as a service, and a "rent-a-car" as a product.

In Australian English, at least, the more common term is probably either "hire car" or "rental car".

As an aside, I wouldn't be surprised if 'rent-a-car' turns out to be trademarked by a company, although a quick google hasn't immediately shown up any likely suspects.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rent) says `Rentacar is a trademark registered in U.S. 1924`

Comment: For the service: "car hire" or perhaps "car rental"; for the car: "hire car".

Comment: JoseK: Thanks! I wonder which company owns it?

Comment: njd: Yep, I agree.